# Where to put custom layout generator?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to write a custom layout generator.  Where do I put it?  Details appreciated!

I have the download from here: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

The null layout is a good example, because it goes through all the layout structure and protocol with trivial layout logic:

Link: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/src/extensions/layout/null.js

You could use the null layout as a base. Instead of putting the nodes all at (0, 0), you would replace that with your own layout logic.